# window.location not working with IE

Tags: internet-explorer, jakarta-ee, web, struts, jboss7.x

The application is created with struts 1.3:

**Deployment details:**

- JBOSS 7.1.1 final
- Windows 2012 Server
- Oracle JDK 1.7
- We have done fronting JBoss with Apache

**JavaScript:**

```
function linkPage(link) {
   $(".submenu").css("display", "none");
   document.location = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/"+link;
}
```

**Struts Link type:**(Working without any issues)

```
<html:link action="/someAction.do?method=showSomthing" styleId="menuselect2">
    <span>Status</span>
    <span class="icon-img">
        <img src="new.png" />
    </span>
</html:link>
```

**Hyperlink:**(where we have problem)

```
<a href="#" id="menuselect2" onclick="linkPage('someAction.do?method=showSomthing')">
    <span>Status</span>
    <span class="icon-img">
        <img src="new.png" />
    </span>
</a>
```

**Info fetched from Fiddler:**

*IE Request:*

```
GET ://xyz.com/someAction.do?method=showSomthing HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: ://xyz.com/login.do;jsessionid=bVkSxQI7CGT3ZJBG-   5m27S85.undefined?method=authenticate
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Host: xyz.com
```

*IE Response:*

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: ://xyz.com/error_page.jsp
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 31 Jul 2014 10:22:25 GMT
```

*Chrome Request:*

```
GET ://xyz.com/someAction.do?method=showSomthing HTTP/1.1
Host: xyz.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2107.2 Safari/537.36
Referer: :// xyz.com/login.do?method=authenticate
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=YXaZMNkM6BQl7M46fAjfS5Rw.undefined
```

*Chrome Response*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: JSP/2.2
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 31 Jul 2014 10:29:01 GMT
```

The application is working both in development and testing servers. But in production getting session timeout error. The difference in production is we have an Apache HTTPd process sits in between the User-agent and the JBoss server.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: And what is the problem? The only description of the problem you give is "it's not working" ...

Comment: The production environment is more expensive for the customer than development and testing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to the cookie issue, IE was running with the default security level settings as medium. Since httpd and JBoss are on different machines we loose the cookie. The struts tag automatically rewrite the URL by adding jsessionid and hence there is no problem of session tracking.